# Extract value in binary image in matlab

Tags: image, image-processing

I have to complete the image processing project. The project is about detect the defect on the surface of apple. I already done the several method which are grayscale, filtering and binary. The question is how to extract the binary value?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking specifically to create a binary image using the intensity image, you could use the [im2bw](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html) function.